# How to replace a single stream/line with multiple line/stream in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I am very new to this, so please bear with me. :(
In a bash script for android where I am trying to replace a single stream of fonts.xml with another set of stream/line which are stored in another xml file, the line is:

```
    <family name="sans-serif">
```

and what I am trying to replace it with is: (which is stored in another xml file)

```
    <family name="sans-serif">
        <font weight="100" style="normal">Thin.ttf</font>
        <font weight="100" style="italic">ThinItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="normal">Light.ttf</font>
        <font weight="300" style="italic">LightItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="normal">Regular.ttf</font>
        <font weight="400" style="italic">Italic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="normal">Medium.ttf</font>
        <font weight="500" style="italic">MediumItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="normal">Bold.ttf</font>
        <font weight="700" style="italic">BoldItalic.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="normal">Black.ttf</font>
        <font weight="900" style="italic">BlackItalic.ttf</font>
    </family>
    <family>
```

the goal is to use custom font as the first font as default via magisk module and Roboto as fallback. How can I replace the first stream with the expected set of stream with sed. I tried several basics sed but none seems to work!

Comment: sed is the wrong tool for the job. Look into xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use sed for this, you can try this implementation that subtitutes out new lines (\n) for an unused character (%), performs the subtitution and then restores the new lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

multi_line_sed()
{
    local find_str="$1"
    local replace_str="$2"
    local unused_char="%"

    # 1. substitute out new lines (for stdin and function arguments)
    # 2. perform replacement
    # 3. restore new lines

    find_str=$(printf "$find_str" | tr "\n" "$unused_char")
    replace_str=$(printf "$replace_str" | tr "\n" "$unused_char")

    tr "\n" "$unused_char" |
    sed "s|${find_str}|${replace_str}|g" |
    tr "$unused_char" "\n"
}

file="fonts.xml"

find_str="<family name=\"sans-serif\">"
replace_str="$(cat custom_font.xml)"

cat "$file" | multi_line_sed "$find_str" "$replace_str"
```

Comment: worked perfectly with a few modification.

Comment: another problem arises if I try to repeat the process with a second set of variables with a 2nd line of codes as `cat "$file" | multi_line_sed "$find_str2" "$replace_str2"`  the first replacement got overruled and only the 2nd one stays as final output, how do I use multiple string replacements in one line?

Comment: `sed` is capable of editing the file in-place with its flag `sed -i`, but `tr` can't.  You can capture the file contents in a variable first and then write everything back to the file at the end.

file_contents=$(cat "$file")

`printf "$tmp" | 
multi_line_sed "$find_str" "$replace_str" |
multi_line_sed "$find_str2" "$replace_str2" > fonts.xml`

Comment: i didn't think of that, I guess that's is what a noob is supposed to be haha. I tried `multi_line_sed "$find_str" "$replace_str" && multi_line_sed "$find_str2" "$replace_str2" > fonts.xml'`. Thank you once again for saving the day.